# How to stop =Cell("filename") from using another Workbook's File path and name

Tags: excel

Workbook1 has a formula =Cell("Filename").
Workbook1's formula returns the path for Workbook2 when Workbook2 is selected!
I only want the path for the workbook where the formula resides.
How might I do that?

Comment: `=CELL("Filename",A1)`

Comment: Thank you so much ... This answers my question

Comment: But I also need a cell to contain the formula=Cell("row") [wkshtSelectedCellRowNumber ] to return the row number of the currently selected row. I use this to Highlight the Row that is selected[Conditional Formatting]. It's also used in worksheet formulas to extract information from the Selected Row [ie. INDIRECT("R" & wkshtSelectedCellRowNumber -1 &  "C"&COLUMN(wkshtInfoAreaSelected),FALSE)]. This is affected by selecting another workbook. Can you 'fix' this for me? Thank You. Kindest Regards

Comment: It might help you to read the [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cell-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf).

Comment: Thank you for that link. I read it in detail and couldn't find any help on my row number issue. Are you able to find the relevant advice? Kindest Regards

Comment: I really appreciate the time you are expending to help a 'beginner'. Thank You.

Comment: Should I 'start' a new question for the Cell("row") issue?

Answer (score 0):

`Cell` returns the information from the last active cell, if you don't specify a cell.
In your case you haven't specified a cell.

Write for example like this:

```
=CELL("filename",J2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ... This answers my question

Comment: Please see my comment to the previous answer. Thank You. Kindest Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Prema and BigBen.
As Prema stated
=Cell("*") returns the information from the last active cell
What I didn't realise when I used the formula =Cell("filename")
Was That the active cell used to return the filename could be in another Workbook!
=Cell("filename",A1) 'locks' the formula to the workbook that it resides in.